# \newcommand question on "hatting" greek letters in one go

Tags: math-mode, macros, greek

I am working a lot with hatted indices such that

```
\( \hat{\mu} \)
```

A way to make this quicker would be to define the command.

```
\newcommand{\hmu}{\hat{\mu}}
```

but I would need to do this for pretty much every Greek letter separately. Is there a "nice" way to do this in one go? So for example, if I write `\hrho` it automatically understands `\hat{\rho}`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You'd have to define all those macros, as TeX would understand `\hmu` as one control sequence (not `\h` with argument `mu`) which has to be defined in order to work.

Comment: Note that `\h\rho` is only one character longer. In `unicode-math`, you could alternatively input Greek letters followed by U+0302, the combining hat accent, but this is less convenient to enter at the keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

You can select a character that you don't need in math mode, make it active and define it to be the `\hat` command. In total you have to type the same number of characters as in your approach with a separate `\h` command for each Greek letter.

Put the following lines into the preamble of your document to use `@` for this purpose.

```
\begingroup
  \lccode`~=`@
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \let~\hat
  }%
\mathcode`@="8000
```

Then `$@\alpha$` will produce an alpha with hat, whereas `name@gmail.com` outside of math-mode will still produce an `@` sign. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \lccode`~=`@
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \let~\hat
  }%
\mathcode`@="8000
\begin{document}
\( @\alpha@\beta@\mu \)

name@gmail.com
\end{document}
```

[image]

For an explanation, see [Defining characters as macros](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars)

Answer (score 7):

The following makes the definitions for the Greek letters that have a special macro (so not for `o` or an uppercase alpha) with a little less lines of code (a for loop over all the macro names):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\defhatgreek[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname h#1\endcsname
      {\hat{\csname #1\endcsname}}%
  }
\@for\zz:=%
  {%
    alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,varepsilon,zeta,eta,theta,vartheta,kappa,%
    lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,varpi,rho,varrho,sigma,varsigma,tau,upsilon,phi,varphi,%
    chi,psi,omega,%
    Gamma,Delta,Theta,Lambda,Xi,Pi,Sigma,Upsilon,Phi,Psi,Omega%
  }\do
  {%
    \expandafter\defhatgreek\expandafter{\zz}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\halpha + \hbeta = \hgamma + \hdelta$
\end{document}
```